# Making a curl to an API and get an specific field from the JSON

Tags: json, shell, parsing, http, curl

I'm doing a curl like the following

```
curl -X GET "https://api.mercadolibre.com/items/MLA511127356"
```

and the response is a JSON, like for example this one:

```
"id": "MLA511127356",
  "site_id": "MLA",
  "title": "Item De Testeo, Por Favor No Ofertar --kc:off",
  "subtitle": null,
  "seller_id": "160252486",
  "category_id": "MLA4967",
  "official_store_id": null,
  "price": 10,
  "base_price": 10,
  "original_price": null,
  "currency_id": "ARS",
  "initial_quantity": 16,
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing json with sed and awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk)

Comment: Youre doing the `curl...` from the terminal... or no?

Comment: yes I'm doing the curl from the terminal

Answer (score 17):

By using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) you could parse the json data instead of the text based parsing.

```
curl -X GET "https://api.mercadolibre.com/items/MLA511127356" | jq '.[].id'
```

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852427/3798111) you can use `grep -Po '"keyThatYouWant":.*?[^\\]",' file.json`. Like that:

```
local result=$(curl -X GET $YOUR_HUGE_URL)
echo $result | grep -Po '"keyThatYouWant":.*?[^\\]",'
```

Answer (score 9):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is pretty impressive but if you do not want to install another dependency, using python is a nice alternative by also giving you some extra flexibility if further processing is desired.

Jist of it is to pipe the json curl result to `python -c`.

Example:

```
curl -X GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/4 | python -c "import sys,json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['email']"
```

Comment: This is almost perfect for my needs. However, I'm at a loss as to why everything has single quotes, and is therefore not valid JSON. When I find an answer to that I'll comment further.
Okay, found it: Wrap `json.load(sys.stdn)['email]` with `json.dumps(json.load(sys.stdn)['email])` (this also works with a final out file ` > results.json` - per my own needs)